# Nginx proxy pass not working with SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx, virtual-machine, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

Currently I have 3 virtual machines running on ESXi one with nginx that is controlling requests. One running apache web server with the website which is the first example. The last one is running nextcloud though snap which is ssl encrypted and gives me that error when I try to run it though nginx. How can I run it through nginx with ssl?

This is the the website that works though nginx

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name URL URL2;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.7;
            proxy_set_header host  URL;
    }
    }
```

This is the one that doesn't work with ssl

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name URL3;
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://192.168.1.17;
            proxy_set_header host URL3;
    }
    }
```

This is the error

```
Secure Connection Failed
The connection to dynanixcloud.ddns.net was interrupted while the page was loading.
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 0):

As per the configuration you displayed, I couldn't find the SSL parameters. As because you are showing **listen 443 ssl**; then you must provide the SSL directives to support the above argument. Something like below

server {

```
listen              443 ssl;
server_name         www.example.com;
ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
...
```

}

Comment: Is there a documentation about ssl setup?

Comment: Hi,There are various articles available online for the ssl installation assuming you have a public CA certificate and have two files with you the private key and the certificate file which contains both the server & intermediate certificate provided by CA.